# Raise ‘PicklingError’error when apply functions in certain class with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use pandas functions in spark with applyInPandas,when I tranform it within a certain class,it raise errors like this:*pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.*

my script run well in function-type coding:

```
from scipy.stats import kendalltau
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def kendall(dat, a, b):
        kentmp = []
        ken = [np.nan, np.nan]
        if type(a) is list:
            if dat.shape[0] > 3:
                for item in a:
                    kentmp.append(kendalltau(dat[item], dat[b])[0])
                tmp = pd.Series(kentmp, index=a).dropna()
                if tmp.shape[0] > 0:
                    cato = tmp.idxmax()
                    if (tmp < 0).any():
                        cato = tmp.abs().idxmax()
                    ken = [cato, tmp[cato]]
            index = ['category', 'corr']
        else:
            if dat.shape[0] >= 10:
                ken = [kendalltau(dat[a], dat[b])[0], dat.shape[0]]
            index = ['corr', 'N']
        return pd.Series(ken, index=index)

def kendall_process(pdf):
        result = pdf.groupby(['step_id','unit_id']).apply(kendall,'process','label')
        result = pd.DataFrame(result).reset_index()
        #result.columns = ['step_id','unit_id','corr','N']
        pdf['label'] = pdf.label.astype('int')
        result_ = pdf.groupby(['step_id','unit_id'])['label'].mean().reset_index()
        result = pd.merge(result,result_,on=['step_id','unit_id'],how='left')
        result.columns = ['step_id','unit_id','corr','N','ratio']
        return result
result = datInOut.groupBy('step_id','unit_id').applyInPandas(kendall_process, schema='step_id string,\
                                                                                        unit_id string,\
                                                                                         corr float,\
                                                                                       N long,\
                                                                                       ratio float')
                                                                                    
result.show(5)
+--------------+--------+-----------+----+-----+
|       step_id| unit_id|       corr|   N|ratio|
+--------------+--------+-----------+----+-----+
|10303_A2AOI300|A2AOI300|       null|null|  0.0|
|17613_A2AOI500|A2AOI500|-0.13477948|  14|  0.5|
|1B304_A2MAC100|A2MAC100|       null|null|  1.0|
|1A106_A2SPR100|A2SPR100|       null|null|  1.0|
|19103_A2AOI800|A2AOI800|       null|null|  0.5|
+--------------+--------+-----------+----+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

but when I tansform it to class type coding,it raise the PicklingError:

```
@staticmethod
def kendall(dat,a,b):
        kentmp=[]
        ken=[np.nan,np.nan]
        if type(a) is list:
            if dat.shape[0]>3:
                for item in a:
                    kentmp.append(kendalltau(dat[item],dat[b])[0])
                tmp=pd.Series(kentmp,index=a).dropna()
                if tmp.shape[0]>0:
                    cato=tmp.idxmax()
                    if (tmp<0).any():
                        cato=tmp.abs().idxmax()
                    ken=[cato,tmp[cato]]
            index=['category','corr']
        else:
            if dat.shape[0]>=10:
                ken=[kendalltau(dat[a],dat[b])[0],dat.shape[0]]
            index=['corr','N']
        return pd.Series(ken,index=index)
@staticmethod
def kendall_delay(pdf):
        result = pdf.groupby(['step_id','equip_id']).apply(QTWorker.kendall,'delay','label')
        result = pd.DataFrame(result).reset_index()
        pdf['label'] = pdf.label.astype('int')
        result_ = pdf.groupby(['step_id', 'equip_id'])['label'].mean().reset_index()
        result = pd.merge(result, result_, on=['step_id', 'equip_id'], how='left')
        result.columns = ['step_id', 'equip_id', 'corr', 'N', 'ratio']
        return result
ret = datQ.groupBy(self.step, self.equip).applyInPandas(self.kendall_delay, schema='step_id string,equip_id string,corr float,N long,ratio float')
```

as see,I've already decorated the funtions used with *staticmethod*,but it still not work. I really wanna how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Even I don't no why,but I've solved it by puting the kendall functions under kendall_delay.
I really wanna figure out the reason of it!

```
@staticmethod
def kendall_process(pdf):
        def kendall(dat, a, b):
            kentmp = []
            ken = [np.nan, np.nan]
            if type(a) is list:
                if dat.shape[0] > 3:
                    for item in a:
                        kentmp.append(kendalltau(dat[item], dat[b])[0])
                    tmp = pd.Series(kentmp, index=a).dropna()
                    if tmp.shape[0] > 0:
                        cato = tmp.idxmax()
                        if (tmp < 0).any():
                            cato = tmp.abs().idxmax()
                        ken = [cato, tmp[cato]]
                index = ['category', 'corr']
            else:
                if dat.shape[0] >= 10:
                    ken = [kendalltau(dat[a], dat[b])[0], dat.shape[0]]
                index = ['corr', 'N']
            return pd.Series(ken, index=index)
        result = pdf.groupby(['step_id','equip_id']).apply(kendall,'process','label')
        result = pd.DataFrame(result).reset_index()
        pdf['label'] = pdf.label.astype('int')
        result_ = pdf.groupby(['step_id', 'equip_id'])['label'].mean().reset_index()
        result = pd.merge(result, result_, on=['step_id', 'equip_id'], how='left')
        result.columns = ['step_id', 'equip_id', 'corr', 'N', 'ratio']
        return result
```